# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name windows authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I had to relocate to another office due to weather related issues. In our old office, when we started an IIS application using windows authentication the application would pull your windows info and immediately sign in using your credentials. At our new location I have the same app and same settings, or so I thought and when a user starts the application a windows username/pass box opens. The correct information is stored there and the user can just hit enter and move on but I was wondering why it doesn't just auto-log in like at my other location? Does something need to be set in web.config?

Comment: I imagine the environments aren't 'exact' it would be helpful to have the differences in connection between machines, which computers are/aren't on the local domain, are you signing in through VPN?  This problem crops up a lot when in one environment a computer is on the trusted site list and some small difference makes the other site not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cached credentials on Windows will impact this. If the IP changes or machine name changes, you can easily fix by going into CredentialManager in the control panel and deleting the old ones, then when you tell it to save credentials next time, it takes you right in.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile